# Python program to implement a matrix to represent a parent - (sub) child relation of a tree

Tags: python

I need a python code to implement a matrix.
The program will take an input `n`.

Then create a matrix `nodes` of size n*n using nested list i.e. a list will contain n list each of size n.
We set each element to 0.
eg: 
n  =3

`[[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]`

Now, for `n-1` times, user will insert 2 integer values separated with a space and we store it as  i , j. We have to update the element (i,j) of matrix `nodes` to `1` if `j is child of i or if j is sub child of i`.
i.e if 3 is parent of 2 and 2 is parent of 4 then
`nodes[2][4]=1; nodes[3][2]=1 and also, nodes[3][4]=1`

I have coded this but this code neglects few cases.

Code:

```
n=int(input())
nodes = [ [0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]

for i in range(n-1):
    u,v = input().split()
    u = int(u)
    v= int(v)

    nodes[u][v] = 1

    for i in range(n):
         if nodes[v][k]==1:     #if v already have a child.
             nodes[u][k]=1      # make child of v the child of u.
```

We saw that for an input of u,v we checked for the child of v (say k) and made it child of u. But what is there already exists a parent of u. How will I make v and k as the child of u's parent?

e.g.
input as following:

1,3   #we make 3 a child of 1. since 3 has no child, we don't make any other node a child of 1.

2,4   #we make 4 a child of 2. since 4 has no child, we don't make any other node a child of 2.

3,2   #we make 2 and 4 a child of 3. but we didn't make 3 and 4 a child of 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
# 2 4
# 6 5
# 5 4
# 3 1
# 4 1
#
# 1
# |\
# 4 3
# |\
# 2 5
#   |
#   6

from functools import *
n = int(input())
childlist = {i: [] for i in range(1, n + 1)}
for _ in range(n - 1):
    a, b = map(int, input().split()) # reads input
    childlist[b] += [a] # builds parent-child relation

@lru_cache(maxsize=None) # memoization
def all_child(node): # returns all child/subchild of node
    if not childlist[node]: return [] # Base case
    return list(set(sum(([child] + all_child(child) for child in childlist[node]), []))) # Recursively gets descendants

# for t in range(1, n + 1):
#     print (all_child(t))

nodes = [[int(j in all_child(i)) for j in range(1, n + 1)] for i in range(1, n + 1)] #
print (nodes)
```

Comment: First, the code presented in unedited form or in its first form was wrong as it was creating (n+1)*(n+1) sized matrix because of `range(n+1)`. But even if we fix the size, the code doesn't give the desired output. It only shows relation between parent and direct child, and not the relation between parent and child of child.

Comment: @Ash sorry, whhat do you mean? I'm creating a `(n+1)*(n+1)` grid since the [0] column/row is not used. If you want to access nodes[1..n] you need (n+1) dimensions. Also, what do you mean it only shows relation between parent and direct child? If 3->1 and 4->2 and you add 2->3, it checks if childlist[2] is empty. In this case it's not, since you had 4->2 i.e. childlist[2]=[4]. Then it adds 4 to childlist[3] and removes childlist[2]. So now childlist[3] = [2, 4]

Comment: I now understand why you created a matrix of dimension of (n+1). But the problem with output still persists. I ran your code in python compiler. For the above mentioned inputs, I wanted the matrix nodes to show that 2,3,4 were child of 1 but it doesn't do so.

Comment: @Ash Oh, so you want to show all parent-child-grandchild-... relation? so like 1->2->3->4->5 then show 1 is child of 5 as well? Can you give a larger test input

Comment: Can you check the output for "2 4\6 5\5 4\3 1\4 1" (those are new lines)? Should 6 be a child of 4? How about 5 a child of 1?

Comment: or are you only considering 2 levels of child

Comment: Yes, I want all parent-child-grandchild relation. `1->2->3->4->5 then show 1 is child of 5 as well?` exactly. I want 1 also be shown as a child of 5.

Comment: I have added my code. See if it works. Notice my code defaults nodes[x][x] = False